# Laravel - Debugbar exception: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, laravel

When I open up my laravel.log file I see that every second it spams this message:

```
[2020-05-24 14:38:15] local.ERROR: Debugbar exception: A non well formed numeric value encountered  
[2020-05-24 14:38:16] local.ERROR: Debugbar exception: A non well formed numeric value encountered  
[2020-05-24 14:38:17] local.ERROR: Debugbar exception: A non well formed numeric value encountered  
[2020-05-24 14:38:18] local.ERROR: Debugbar exception: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

How do I track down from where the errors comes from?

Comment: This might help - https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/586

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your dependencies with `composer update`. It seems there was a issue with `symfony/var-dumper` package which should be already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

can you try delete the file .log and try again, other option is

```
1.- composer update
2.- php artisan config:clear
2.- php artisan view:clear
2.- php artisan route:clear
```

if the problem continue try to unistall and install again de debugbar, or check the version...

Comment: The big problem for me is that, I'm working on a project that is mainly built by another person who doesn't work on it anymore and there is no `composer.json` file in `/var/www/html` , but the project is using a pretty decent amount of external dependencies. Is there a way to somehow generate `composer.json` file based on what's inside `/var/www/html/vendor` ?